# CarrierWave Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I get an error that looks like this:

```
   NoMethodError (undefined method `image_will_change!' for #<Bar:0x24ddda0>):
  app/controllers/bars_controller.rb:43:in `new'
  app/controllers/bars_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

After I click submit for a registration. I am using Carrierwave and have followed the steps to using it, but still have an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CarrierWave doesn't support the `attribute_will_change!` call, at least I ran into this error a few times. Follow the steps from [How to: Detect a new file in a mounted uploader](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Detect-a-new-file-in-a-mounted-uploader) at  [CarrierWave's wiki](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki) which provide similar functionality.

Comment: Now I have an issue that come up: undefined method `moderated=' for #<Bar:0x24510f8>

Comment: Fixed it. Forgot to migrate the new column!