# carrierwave - rails 3.1- undefined method: image_will_change

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave, railscasts

I get an error that look like this:

```
undefined method `post_image_will_change!' for #<Post:0xf4e9184>
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:43:in `new'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

I've included this in my "post" model:

```
 attr_accessible :title, :name, :content, :post_image
 mount_uploader :post_image, PostImageUploader
```

and in _form.html.erb I've added:

```
 :html =>  { :multipart => true }
```

I looked [CarrierWave Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822498/carrierwave-error) but that doesn't help me.

Any clues of what generates that error? I've migrated the database and so forth (followed the railscasts guide on carrierwave exactly..)

Comment: can you please share your `posts_controller.rb` file?

Comment: did u add the new migration files for image? :)

Comment: manged to fix it.. had made an extreme rookie misstake. Ty anyway

Comment: What mistake was that.  I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The OP comments that he fixed it, however there's no answer set so I thought I'd add one for people coming across this in the future, which included myself until I figured it out :)

undefined method `x_will_change!' for # happens if you forget to add a column in your model's db table. If you have a model User and a AvatarUploader, with the uploader mounted as in the Carrierwave docs:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

Then the error will read

```
undefined method `avatar_will_change!' for #<User:0x00...>
```

To fix it (based on this example) add a column in a migration run the following in the console:

```
rails g migration AddAvatarToUsers avatar:string
```

This will generate the following migration:

```
class AddAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :avatar, :string
  end
end
```

Then migrate to apply the change (again in the console):

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: nice 1+ forgot to add image column here aswell

Comment: Switched branches and reset db in other branch, forgot to migrate in this one. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that author just forgot to run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

ALso, if you met such error inside of your tests then you should run:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, for anyone getting this error on heroku, you need to run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and

```
heroku restart
```

in the terminal after adding/removing fields/tables from your database.

Comment: saved the day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Kreek, this is obviously a minor oversight, as most people would have realized by now, you probably meant to run this command, as one should, outside the console, otherwise, one would get the following:

'NameError: undefined local variable or method `migrate' for main:Object'.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but mine was because I was copying and pasting codes and forgot to delete

```
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
```

from my model which did not use pictures.
Hope this help others in future who could not figure out what happened